lime plastering over chicken mesh or reed
we are trying to put up walls for our insulated walls. We used fiberglass insulation and currently just put up chicken wires (not super flat but we are fine with the wall having curves here and there) with the hope that they will hold lime plaster.
But I started to wonder if the chicken wires were strong enough, and if the wall will fall down one day.
There are no backing boards whatsoever, just insulation foam.
Should we switch to reed fences and plaster over that instead? Seems like it is stronger..

Are you using fiberglass insulation or insulation foam? Both? Something else entirely? Maybe include a pic or two of the situation to help us help you. In general, though, the plaster pushes through the wire mesh to hold on to the wall. Maybe explain your concern about the wire being "strong enough" and the wall "falling down".

There's also the 300-year-old technology called lath and plaster that worked then and still works now. And then why not just drywall? It's the cheapest, easiest, fastest way to finish interior walls.

If there is no structure, just plaster and wire over foam, you will have a very weak wall.  It may be suitable for blocking an opening, but in time it will fail.

There are walls with a metal mesh supporting plaster; I had to help break one down. (Ugh.) But the mesh is much denser and more rigid than chicken wire. If you want to go this route rather than drywall, use the right materials rather than guessing and using whatever is on hand.
